# Django rest framrwork Nested Serializer's fields not appearing in parent serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In my Django app (using drf), I've modified my model's serializer to get the front-end's desired input, but I'm having zero luck trying to nest this serializer inside another one.

I've tried creating a field of the model with the to_representation method and putting a get_photos method, none of which amounted to anything.

```
# models.py

class Photo(models.Model):
    photo = models.OneToOneField(RawPhoto, related_name='contest_photo', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    thumbnail_size = models.OneToOneField(PhotoSize, related_name='contest_photo', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    thumbnail_url = models.TextField(verbose_name='thumbnail_url')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Contest Photo'

    @property
    def get_photo_src(self):
        return settings.MEDIA_URL + self.photo.image.name

    @property
    def get_thumbnail_url(self):
        # dont forget to add cache
        if len(self.thumbnail_url) == 0:
            file_name = self.get_photo_src
            last_dot = file_name.rfind('.')
            photo_name, photo_extension = file_name[:last_dot], file_name[last_dot:]
            self.thumbnail_url = photo_name + '_' + self.thumbnail_size.name + photo_extension

        return self.thumbnail_url

# serializers.py

class PhotoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    thumbnail_height = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='thumbnail_size.height')
    thumbnail_width = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='thumbnail_size.width')
    src = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='get_photo_src')
    thumbnail_url = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='get_thumbnail_url')
    caption = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='photo.caption')
    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ['src', 'thumbnail_url', 'thumbnail_height', 'thumbnail_width', 'caption']

class GallerySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    photos = PhotoSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Gallery
        fields = ['title', 'photos']
```

PhotoSerializer actually returns the full description of the object that I expect from it, but when I nest it inside GallerySerializer, it only shows thumbnail_url, which is the only field that is included in the model itself.
Is there anyway I can include PhotoSerializer's fields inside GallerySerializer? (which is supposed to be a list of Photos)

Thanks.

Comment: add `depth=1` under the `class Meta` of the `GallerySerializer`

Answer (score 2):

use the depth argument as described [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization)

```
class GallerySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    photos = PhotoSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        depth=1
        model = Gallery
        fields = ['title', 'photos']
```

Comment: I did, but it didn't make a difference.
api/photos/1 gives:
{
    "src": "/images/blah.png",
    "thumbnail_url": "/images/blah_thumbnail.png",
    "thumbnail_height": 300,
    "thumbnail_width": 400,
    "caption": "123"
}

api/galleries/1 gives:
{
    "title": "test",
    "photos": [
        {
            "thumbnail_url": "/images/blah_thumbnail.png"
        }
    ]
}